# php Date comparing

Tags: php, date

```
$month = [
   "January",
   "February",
   "March",
   "April",
   "May",
   "June",
   "July",
   "August",
   "September",
   "October",
   "November",
   "December"
];

$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$dateOfDoc = "$year/$month/$day";
$date_now = date("Y/m/d");

if($dateOfDoc >= $date_now){
    echo"yes u can upload";
} else {
    echo "no u can't upload";
}
```

I am trying to compare today and the user input date and I should allow user if the user input date should be more than today but I always get false part even user put tomorrow's date 
example )

```
today : 2019 04 25
user date : 2019 04 05 return false

today : 2019 04 25
user date : 2019 12 05 return true
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your $dateOfDoc variable is just string, not date. Convert it to date.

Comment: Why are you generating any array of month names, only to then overwrite the variable you stored this in right after? What were the actual values of $dateOfDoc and $date_now, when you used `var_dump` to make debug outputs?

Comment: Alternatively, `strtotime`, then compare as you would.

Comment: @ismakv date is a string finally. if date is proper string everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing date format with separator `/`

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$dateOfDoc = "$month/$day/$year";
$date_now = date("m/d/Y");

if($dateOfDoc >= $date_now){
    echo"yes u can upload";
} else {
    echo "no u can't upload";
}
```

> **Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking**
>   **at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a**
>   **slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the**
>   **separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format**
>   **is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and**
>   **the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.**

Source [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b1778bfacfb94a48603983dd6506f2093297acf).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$current_date = date('d/m/y');
$post_date = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['day'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['year']));

if (strtotime($post_date) >= strtotime($current_date)) {
 echo 'Upload';
} else {
 echo 'Do not upload';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Text strings with Digits!

if $name contains Name of month you can't compare it with date("m") in php since date("m") in php return digital number of month but you store name of month in your variable $name

all of your parameters to compare should be have equal format